# How can I load part of a .mat file that is too big in memory for my machine?

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I have a big .mat file that I want to process, but it is too big to fit in a single load. I thought to load it in parts, each time to access just the important parameters. So I have practically two questions:

1. How can I access the variables names of the mat file without loading it?
2. How can I load only one of them to the workspace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can see the list of variables using:

```
vars = whos('-file','name.mat');
```

and then just load the variable you want, say the first one on the list, by:

```
load('name.mat', vars(1).name)
```

Answer (score 9):

As well as loading individual variables from the .mat file as suggested by @natan, in recent versions of MATLAB you can use a `matfile` object to load in only parts of an individual variable.

So for example, you can say:

```
myFile = matfile('path\to\the\mat\file');
loadedData = myfile.myVarName(100:200, 500:600);
```

and you will load in only a portion of the variable `myVarName` from the file `myFile`.

---

Edit:

The `matfile` object also has methods `size`, `who` and `whos`, so that you can determine the names and sizes of the variables that the file contains before you attempt to load bits in.

Comment: it should be noted that `matfile` only supports MAT-file v7.3 (HDF5-based) for partial loading, otherwise it falls back to loading the entire variable.