# Java - Read only parts of .mat file

Tags: java, matlab, hdf5

I'm trying to read some portions of a .mat file, **version v7.3**, inside my Java application.

In particular, I'd like to load only some parts of a variable stored inside the .mat file.

Matlab supports this feature for that version of file, by using the command **matfile** (more info [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html)).

A good example of what I want to achieve is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17524044/4948006).

The file I have to process contains 1xN rows, like the field Date, as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

I couldn't find any Java library able to support .mat v7.3, but since that version of file is **HDF5-based**, I tried to implement a solution that processes the file considering it as HDF5 one.
I'm using [**JHDF** libray](https://github.com/jamesmudd/jhdf), but I can't understand if it supports a matfile like command.

In particular, I'd like to extract data from Duration field, only when Date field assumes a particular value. Date contains dates in the format yyyymmdd, as integer values, in ascending order.

Let's say I want to read data from Duration, when Date = 20230211. I implemented this with JHDF, as follows:

```
HdfFile hdfFile = new HdfFile(Paths.get("file.mat"));
int[] dateArr = (int[]) hdfFile.getDatasetByPath("/Task/Date").getDataFlat();
if (dateArr.length > 0) {
    int startIdx = 0;
    int finalIdx = dateArr.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
        if (dateArr[i] == 20230211) {
            startIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = startIdx + 1; i < dateArr.length; i++) {
        if (dateArr[i] > 20230211) {
            finalIdx = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    float[] duration = (float[]) hdfFile.getDatasetByPath("/Task/Duration").getDataFlat();
    float[] desiredDuration = Arrays.copyOfRange(duration, startIdx, finalIdx + 1);
}
```

Do you know what I can do to emulate the matfile command in Java?

Comment: You could try using JMatio.

Comment: What have you tried? You should share your code and ask for an specific example. Note that recommendation of libraries is off topic in Stackoverlow.

Comment: @AliasCartellano JMatIO does not support .mat v7.3 files. I tried to use it, without success.

Comment: Hi I am the jhdf developer and would be happy to help. Im not exactly clear on the structure of your file and what part you want to open. Maybe try opening a example file in HDFView, and then add the tree to the question, or open an issue on github. Seeing an example file would really help. I should a an example to the docs but try looking at `Dataset#getData(long[] sliceOffset, int[] sliceDimensions)` that reads part of a dataset.

Comment: Hi @JamesMudd, I edited the question, adding more info about the file structure and the code.

Comment: Hi @JamesMudd, is there a better way to code what I implemented, with JHDF?

Comment: As you need to search through the `Date` dataset to find the required points you need to load all the data in that case. If the `Duration` dataset is significantly larger (I suspect its not in this case) then you could load only the data you want there but that wouldn't be a significant improvement here.

Comment: @AliasCartellano can you tell me why JMatIO is still getting recommended on SO in 2023? That library was abandoned 12 years ago, the >5 subsequent forks were abandoned a few years later, and even the combined fork MatFileRW hasn't seen changes in 7 years. I'm generally curious why StackOverflow and ChatGPT keep recommending an abandoned SourceForge repo rather than at least a more updated fork or alternatives like MFL (also doesn't support mat7.3 at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title and description of your use-case, it seems that you need to use HDF5 point or hyperslab selections to read data partially (i.e. some parts of it).

If you are not bound to a particular HDF5 library, you may want to try [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com), a high-level (declarative) programming language to manage HDF5 data, which is used below to illustrate the aforementioned type of selections in Java.

```
// create a chunked dataset named 'dset' of type int with one dimension (size 1000) 
HDFql.Execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET dset AS INT(1000)");

// read element stored in position #50 of 'dset' using a point selection
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM dset[49]");

// read elements stored in positions #100 and #200 of 'dset' using a point selection
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM dset[99; 199]");

// read elements stored in positions #50 through #70 of 'dset' using an (regular) hyperslab selection
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM dset[49:::20]");

// read elements stored in positions #10 through #20 and positions #200 through #500 of 'dset' using an (irregular) hyperslab selection
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM dset[9:::10 OR 199:::300]");
```

Comment: How can I import HDFql in a Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 0):

**1.-**

if the `.mat` file was created with `matfile` and `'Writable'` was set to `false` then you have do

```
matfile(filename,'Writable',true)
```

otherwise `filename` is read only.

If the .mat file was created like this

```
hm=matfile('filename.mat')
```

`hm` being the handle to such newly created `.mat` file then check `'Writable'` status with

```
m.Properties.Writable
```

**2.-**

In the following link you will find out that precisely to interface .mat files at Mathworks there's a product called **MATLAB builder JA**

https://uk.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/100293-how-can-i-read-mat-files-from-java.html?fq%5B%5D=asset_type_name:answer&fq%5B%5D=category:compiler_sdk/java_packages&page=1

**3.-**

If it's not `'Writable'` and **MATLAB builder JA** is out of range, the same QA in the link I just supplied points at going down to C/C++ and writting your own function to connect **MATLAB LIBMAT** with **JNI API**.

For either **2.-** or **3.-** you are going to need **MATLAB Compiler**.

**Additional Comment**

In this page

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/list-of-examples.html

you will find links to functions in C that you can use from JAVA to import `.mat` files.

However since Mathworks has a toolbox to such purpose, **Builder JA**, it may be the case that you will have to modify the free  functions available in the last link I supply in this answer, or add something, which would be the work already solved in the toolbox **Builder JA** suggested in point 2.

Why don't you install the **Builder JA** trial that is free for 30 days and assess whether you really need **Builder JA**?

Then you will be able to consider whether keeping **Builder JA**, at a price, or go for the do-it-yourself option.

Comment: If I correctly understood, you suggest me to use MATLAB Builder JA or to write my own library using MATLAB LIBMAT

Comment: I have added an additional comment that answers this.